# Cross Server Cookies, PHP

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

We have 2 web servers, one secure and one normal.

Is it possible to set a cookie like this

```
setcookie("basket[id]", $newID, time()+60*60*24, "/", SITE_URL, 0, true);  
setcookie("basket[id]", $newID, time()+60*60*24, "/", SECURE_SITE_URL, 1, false);
```

Where

```
SITE_URL = www.sitename.com  
SECURE_SITE_URL = xxxxx.securesitename.com
```

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

## Set Cookie

With [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) you can set the domain parameter to indicate where the cookie is available. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com then you'd set it to '.example.com'. The . is not required but makes it compatible with more browsers.

As long as your servers are referred to with different sub-domains, you can set your cookies accordingly.

### Secure parameter

Secure, indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client.

## Setting a Cookie on a different domain

A server cannot set a cookie for a domain that it isn't a member of.

The server issuing the cookie must be a member of the domain that it tries to set in the cookie. That is, a server called www.myserver.com cannot set a cookie for the domain www.yourserver.com.

### How Double Click do it

One exception to the rule is ad agency Double click. Who manage to add cookies to your PC without you visiting the specific web site by packaging cookies with image requests when they are loaded from their servers onto other peoples web sites.

Comment: www.sitename.com and secure.sitename.com should work with a single cookie, but what he's trying to do is setting the cookies across domains (sitename / securesitename) not only subdomains.

Comment: Thanks guys, thats what i was afraid of.

Comment: You cannot set cookie cross domain. However, if you really want this, then you could set cookie for your domain/subdomain and include in the body a 1x1 pixes or invisible iframe to other domain including a short lived token that allows the other domain to set the same cookie in the other domain (or you can use http redirect). Both domains can of course be served off the same host using virtual hosts with 1 minor complication if https is involved. Are you trying cross domain SSO?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a cookie for a domain other than the current or a superset of it (like *example.com* is a superset of *foo.example.com* and *bar.example.com*). That means the second *Set-Cookie* will get rejected by the browser.

One solution is to use a subdomain of your main domain for your secure domain, like *secure.example.com*. Then a cookie set for `.example.com` would be available at *www.example.com* as well as at *secure.example.com*.